# Shrinkwrap maven-resolver

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I´m using Shrinkwrap to resolve my .xml in my DAO

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment()
{
    File[] files = Maven.resolver().resolve("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.11").withTransitivity().asFile();
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "morphological-analysis-data-access-object-test.war")
            .addPackages(true,"com.root")
            .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"))
            .addAsLibraries(files);
}
```

and I get 2 errors on the tests:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

and

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke deployment method

I had some DAO tests working, but while a continued to write the remaining tests this error started and affected both the ones I was writing and the ones that were fine before.

Something that I change: instead adding a million of `.addClass`, I use `.addPackages`.

My best guess is that I need to resolve my .iml as well. That make any sense?

Complete stack trace:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lbr/com/cpmh/untitled/analysis/spine/BenzelPolygonAnalysis;

```
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getSortedDeclaredFields(TestClass.java:77)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.<init>(Arquillian.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.container.JUnitTestRunner.execute(JUnitTestRunner.java:61)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:139)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:117)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:86)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1349)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.cpmh.untitled.analysis.spine.BenzelPolygonAnalysis from [Module "deployment.morphological-analysis-data-access-object-test.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 70 more

Comment: Can you add the complete stacktrace of the error?

Comment: @Lorelorelore it help?

Comment: It seems you are missing BenzelPolygonAnalysis. Where does this class come from? Is it one of yours or it comes from another jar?

Comment: @Lorelorelore It is a original class of this DAO that i´m testing, this bug repeats in every class on my project, something broke down and i don´t know what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load your classes with `.addPackages(true,"com.root")` then everything in that package will be loaded including subpackages recursively. It seems that you have no class `br.com.cpmh.untitled.analysis.spine.BenzelPolygonAnalysis` in the war Arquillian is creating. Maybe you are missing another `addPackages` for package `br.com.cpmh`.

You should check if the war file is created correctly. There are two ways for doing this.
You can use the following property in `arquillian.xml`:

```
<engine>
   <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/deployments</property>
</engine>
```

Or you can modify your `@Deployment` method in this way:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment()
{
    File[] files = Maven.resolver().resolve("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.11").withTransitivity().asFile();
    WebArchive archive =ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "morphological-analysis-data-access-object-test.war")
        .addPackages(true,"com.root")
        .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
        .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"))
        .addAsLibraries(files);
    archive.as(ZipExporter.class).exportTo(new File("/" + archive.getName()), true);
    return archive;
}
```

Comment: Tried both and now the DAO test are being ignored

Comment: What does it mean? Is there any error or warning in console?

Comment: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1152)

Comment: This should be another question. Probably it is not related to the first problem you encountered.

Comment: 11:58:28,937 ERROR [org.jboss.as.txn] (default task-1) WFLYTX0003: APPLICATION ERROR: transaction still active in request with status 1

Comment: As the error as changed, you should ask another question, because this seems another problem.

Comment: Aparently is working, but i have another error, i´m gona open another question to that erro. Thanks a lot @Lorelorelore.